# Can props be written to override connect() in react-redux?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, refactoring, react-redux

I'm tasked with refactoring out an overuse of unneeded dependency injection using ReactJS/Redux.

The dependencies are injected using props within JSX markup like so:

```
<CardContainer
  addCountry={actions.addCountry}
  addDateRange={actions.addDateRangeFilter}
  addDistributor={actions.addDistributor}
  addListFilterItem={actions.addListFilterItem}
  addListFilterWithOneItem={actions.addListFilterWithOneItem}
  {/* ...other props removed for brevity */}
/>
```

These props are repeated in several places all over the codebase (and for multiple components like this one).

I'm going through and removing the need to pass these functions as props to the `CardContainer` class and in its place using **connect()** (from the `react-redux` npm package) like so:

```
export default connect(undefined, dispatch => ({
  actions: bindActionCreators(MyActions, dispatch),
}))(class DistributorFilterPaneCards extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    addCountry: PropTypes.func,
    addDateRange: PropTypes.func,
    addDistributor: PropTypes.func,
    addListFilterItem: PropTypes.func,
    addListFilterWithOneItem: PropTypes.func,
```

What I've found though is that **very rarely** there is a prop, **addCountry** for example, that is passed a different function than all the others.

Basically, I want to have **connect()** work like the **static defaultProps** object. Is there a graceful way to allow **connect()** to be overridden by props passed through JSX so I can refactor it as needed instead of all over the codebase at once?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than modifying the default behavior globally, I would recommend creating a defaultProps object, importing that where you need it, and applying it like so:

`default_props.js`

```
module.exports = {
  addCountry: actions.addCountry,
  addDateRange: actions.addDateRangeFilter,
  addDistributor: actions.addDistributor,
  addListFilterItem: actions.addListFilterItem,
  addListFilterWithOneItem: actions.addListFilterWithOneItem
};
```

`some react component file`

```
var defaultProps = require('default_props.js');

...

<CardContainer {...defaultProps} />
```

You could event make `defaultProps` a function that takes an optional argument for different cases:

```
var defaultProps = (useCase) {
  useCase = useCase || 'standard';

  var props = {};

  if (useCase === 'weird-component') {
    //don't include some default property
  }

  return props;
};
```

Useful reading: https://zhenyong.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html